# "As I told you," vs "as I have told you."

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

What's the difference between the two? Is the latter more formal? Example:

> As I (have) told you before, I didn't know the victim.

Both have many results in Google Books: [As I told you before](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22As%20I%20told%20you%20before%22&biw=1280&bih=891&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ei=r0xPVbz3NI7p8AWS2ICoAg&ved=0CA4Q_AUoAQ). [As I have told you before](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1280&bih=891&tbm=bks&q=%22As%20I%20have%20told%20you%20before%22&oq=%22As%20I%20have%20told%20you%20before%22&gs_l=serp.3...40380.42300.0.42499.11.10.1.0.0.0.163.785.4j3.7.0.msedr...0...1c.1.64.serp..7.4.471.7LpXZVQbALQ).

So I'm sure they're both grammatically correct.

Comment: Did I tell you this more than once?

Comment: I would be inclined to use "as I told you" if I told him _once_, and "as I have told you" if I had told him multiple times (of course, in that case, I might add "multiple times" or "repeatedly" for emphasis.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both versions are grammatical, and the difference between them is pretty subtle. (It's hard for me to imagine a situation where one would be correct, but the other not.)

To my ear, *as I told you* refers to one or more specific instances of my telling you. I would use it if I were emphasizing that I had, for instance, upheld my responsibility to inform you of something.

The perfect tense, *as I have told you,* on the other hand, is used to allude to the consequences or implications of past action, and doesn't require me to have a particular time in mind. In fact, it would be ungrammatical to say, *#as I have told you yesterday, ....*

I would use *as I have told you* if I were emphasizing that you should already know the thing I told you.

Answer (score -2):

I agree with the above from a grammatical point of view, which doesn't mean one would not find the sentence "I have told you yesterday" in the spoken and written language.